# Move multiple files to a dir if their names contain the same string present in dir name

Tags: command-line, scripts, mv

I have multiple files in one folder:

```
ABA.xy
BEB.xy
ACA.xy
```

The same files with different extension in another folder

```
ABA.rr
BEB.rr
ACA.rr
```

Then I have single folder for each file name

```
ABA
BEB
ACA
```

I would like to do the following. if the file with extension `.xy` and `.rr` have the same name as the folder, move to that folder.
For example

```
ABA.xy and ABA.rr in ABA
```

I am familiar with `mv` but I think that here I have to write a small script to do that.

Comment: What to do with filenames without extension?

Comment: this are folder not files

Comment: You are referring to files in the first two sections of your question (with different extension).

Comment: Yes I have files with the same name but different extensions. Then I have folders with the same name of the files. I want to move the files whatever extension they have in the folder that has a similar name.

Comment: But files do not necessarily have an extension (in general). Should they be moved as well?

Comment: I think I quite do not get what you are asking. All my files are either `.xy` or `.rr`

Comment: Answers here are normally created for a purpose (if possible) broader then your situation. It should be applicable also if files have no extension.

Comment: I understand, well than I would say that I am open for everything as far as the file with no extension are concerned.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming your files stored in `source` dir and your target folders are in `dest` like following tree:

```
$ tree source
source
├── dir1
│   ├── ABA.xy
│   ├── ACA.xy
│   └── BEB.xy
└── dir2
    ├── ABA.rr
    ├── ACA.rr
    └── BEB.rr
2 directories, 6 files

$ tree dest
dest
├── ABA
├── ACA
└── BEB
3 directories, 0 files
```

The command would be:

```bsh
find source -type f -exec sh -c 'noext="${0%.*}"; echo mv '{}' "dest/${noext##*/}/"' {} \;
```

- the `source` is the source directory or specify the parent directory.
- `noext="${0%.*}"` strips the files extension and saves the result into `noext` variable.
- `"${noext##*/}"` removes the file path portion from `noext` variable and pickup the only file name.
- `dest` directory is destination parent directory.
- So `mv '{}' "dest/${noext##*/}/"'` moves the current file to `dest/$noext` directory.

  The content of `noext` in above command is only filename without extension and path in it that specify the destination directory which is the same name as the current file name.

[Here is a sample test that show the result of command](http://paste.ubuntu.com/9959900/)

Note that this commands used `echo` for testing and dry run. If you ensure about what you are do, remove the `echo` in front of `mv` command to perform actual moving.

Answer (score 2):

A slightly different approach using `rename`:

```
rename 's#.*/(.+)(\.\w+)#mkdir "dest/$1"; "dest/$1/$1$2"#e' source/{a,b}/*
```

This is essentially just using a regular expression to translate the paths. We use a little bit of Perl (which `rename` supports) to create the new directories and rename moves the file at the end.

It isn't too clever. It won't search for cases where there isn't a corresponding file (we could search and remove directories with only one file) and it'll probably explode if there are files without extensions.

```
$ mkdir -p source/{a,b} dest
$ touch source/a/{ABA,BEB,ACA}.xy
$ touch source/b/{ABA,BEB,ACA}.rr
$ tree
.
├── dest
└── source
    ├── a
    │   ├── ABA.xy
    │   ├── ACA.xy
    │   └── BEB.xy
    └── b
        ├── ABA.rr
        ├── ACA.rr
        └── BEB.rr

$ rename 's#.*/(.+)(\.\w+)#mkdir "dest/$1"; "dest/$1/$1$2"#e' source/{a,b}/*
$ tree
.
├── dest
│   ├── ABA
│   │   ├── ABA.rr
│   │   └── ABA.xy
│   ├── ACA
│   │   ├── ACA.rr
│   │   └── ACA.xy
│   └── BEB
│       ├── BEB.rr
│       └── BEB.xy
└── source
    ├── a
    └── b
```